# ¿Cómo interpretar un string para obtener sus clases y métodos?

Tags: javascript, python, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy buscando la forma de poder interpretar una expresión situada en un campo en una tabla de Oracle.

```
Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo('valor') ==0 && 
Objeto.getNombreFuncion("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo('valor')
```

Necesito obtener las clases (Objeto), los métodos (getNombreFuncion) y los parametros de los métodos.

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue programar un lexer y un parser en python para poder realizar el desglose, pero por motivos de tiempo y recursos estoy buscando una alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que quieres, pero en cualquier lenguaje puedes usar algunas expresiones regulares para ir sacando los datos:

```js
const string = `Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo("valor") ==0 && 
Objeto.getNombreFuncion("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo("valor")`;

const clases = string.match(/\b\w+(?=\.)/gi);

const metodos = string.match(/\.\w+(?=())/gi);

const parametros = string.match(/(?<=("))\w*(?=\"())/gi);

console.log(clases);

console.log(metodos);

console.log(parametros);
```

Si quieres además saber de que clase son los métodos y de que métodos son los parámetros, usas los resultados que vas obteniendo de límite para las siguientes expresiones.

```js
const string = `Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo("valor") ==0 && 
Objeto2.getNombreFuncion2("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta").compareTo("valor")`;

const clases = string.match(/\b\w+(?=\.)/gi);

clases.forEach(obj=>{

  console.log("metodos de clase "+obj);

  const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=${obj}.)\\w+(?=())`,"gi");
 
  console.log(string.match(regex));

})
```